# How can I access local variables from inside a C++11 anonymous function?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, scope, anonymous-function

I'm doing a simple normalization on a vector (weights), trying to make use of STL algorithms to make the code as clean as possible (I realize this is pretty trivial with for loops):

```
float tot = std::accumulate(weights.begin(), weights.end(), 0.0);
std::transform(weights.begin(), weights.end(), [](float x)->float{return(x/tot);});
```

At present, tot is not visible to the anonymous function, so this doesn't compile. What's the best way of making a local variable visible to the anonymous function?

Comment: sorry, 0 should have been 0.0! edited

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need a closure.

```
float tot = std::accumulate(weights.begin(), weights.end(), 0);
std::transform(weights.begin(), weights.end(), [tot](float x)->float{return(x/tot);});
```

In this case `tot` is captured by value. C++11 lambdas support capturing by:

1. value `[x]`
2. reference `[&x]`
3. any variable currently in scope by reference `[&]`
4. same as 3, but by value `[=]`

You can mix any of the above in a comma separated list `[x, &y]`.

Comment: Great! Is there a good web/book reference on C++11 anonymous function usage in STL? A lot of what I found on the web was either outdated workarounds for anonymous functions, or random blog postings.

Comment: @bd1 The wikipedia on C++0x is actually quite good. Also the last standard draft available to the public is called n3424. Unfortunately there are no books on C++0x yet.

Comment: If you make a closure with `[=]` and it makes copies of _all_ the variables in enclosing scope, does that include global variables? When does it stop going up the scope ladder?

Comment: @Seth I should have been more explicit: Only entities that are actually (odr-)used inside the lambda-body are captured when a capture-default (`&` or `=`) is used. That means a copy of the global will only be made, if you access the global. See §5.1.2.11 for capture-defaults and §5.1.2.9 for the scoping rules.

Answer (score 12):

The lambda can "capture" variables from the ambient scope:

```
[ ..., N, ... ](int a, int b) -> int  { return (a + b) * N; }
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^
 captured vars  local params     ret.type
```

You can capture by value or by reference, and you can use the special syntax `[=]` and `[&]` to capture *anything* from the ambient scope, i.e. anything you actually end up using.

Comment: What if I am parsing a lambda as a function parameter. It throws an error saying the lambda function is not the right type for the parameter.

Comment: @Acidic: Since you cannot say the *type* of a lambda expression, it's very difficult to have *functions* whose parameter is a closure type. Typically, you would use function *templates* to deduce the type, or a type-erasing wrapper such as `std::function` if you need to manage heterogeneous collections of callables.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `tot` to the "capture list":

```
float tot = std::accumulate(weights.begin(), weights.end(), 0);
std::transform(weights.begin(), weights.end(), [tot](float x)->float{return(x/tot);});
```

Alternatively you can use a capture-default to capture `tot` implicitly:

```
float tot = std::accumulate(weights.begin(), weights.end(), 0);
std::transform(weights.begin(), weights.end(), [=](float x)->float{return(x/tot);});
```